# Prove that $f(D_4) \cap A_4$ is normal in $S_4$

Tags: group-theory

Let $f: D_4 \rightarrow S_4$ be a 1-1 group homomorphism induced by the action of $D_4$ on the vertices of the square. I want to prove that $H = f(D_4) \cap A_4$ is normal in $S_4$ where $S_4$ is the symmetric group, $A_4$ is the alternating group and $D_4$ is the dihedral group. This is what I have so far:

Since conjugation preserves cyclic structure, for any $h \in H$, $\sigma h \sigma^{-1}$ will be even since $h$ is even and $\sigma h \sigma^{-1} \in A_4$

How do I show that $\sigma h \sigma^{-1} \in f(D_4)$ in a simple matter? I can list out the elements of $f(D_4)$ and I know that it contains all the elements of $S_4$ with the $(2)(2)$ cyclic structure, but I don't know how to explicitly prove that.

Comment: my apologies for the mistake, that's what I meant

Comment: Wouldn't the list be a (very) explicit proof?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof without getting your fingers dirty with individual group elements (well, almost at least):

First note that a Sylow-$3$ subgroup of $S_4$ is not normal in $S_4$. Otherwise it would be unique, and then $S_4$ would contain only two elements of order $3$, which it doesn't (that's the part where you in fact need to look at group elements). As a corollary, we know that $A_4$, too, contains non-normal Sylow-$3$ subgroups (otherwise, the unique Sylow-$3$ subgroup of $A_4$ would be characteristic in $A_4$ and thus normal in $S_4$, a contradiction).

With this information, we know by Sylow's theorem that $A_4$ contains $4$ Sylow-$3$ subgroups which necessarily intersect trivially, so $A_4$ must contain $8$ elements of order $3$ (okay, we could as well have counted here).
But this implies that a Sylow-$2$ subgroup of $A_4$ must be unique and thus normal.

Now we have $|f(D_4)|=8$, so $f(D_4)\not\le A_4$ by Lagrange. Since $A_4\trianglelefteq S_4$ and $A_4$ is a maximal subgroup of $S_4$, this implies $f(D_4)A_4=S_4$, and therefore

$$|f(D_4)\cap A_4|=\frac{|f(D_4)|\cdot|A_4|}{|S_4|}=\frac{8\cdot 12}{24}=4,$$

i.e. $f(D_4)\cap A_4$ is a Sylow-$2$ subgroup of $A_4$. Together with the observation above we know that $f(D_4)\cap A_4$ is normal and thus characteristic in $A_4$ which implies

$$f(D_4)\cap A_4\trianglelefteq S_4.$$